# Azure-Powershell Script error (ip address increment )

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I hope you all doing well

can you please help me to solve this problem?

```
$ipnumber = 3
$RgName = "test"
$Location = "test"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ipnumber; $i++) {
    $res1 = -join ((1..10) | ForEach-Object { get-random -minimum 97 -maximum 122 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } })
    $res2 = -join ((1..10) | ForEach-Object { get-random -minimum 97 -maximum 122 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } })
    
    $PublicIP = '$PublicIP'
    $IpConfigName = '$IpConfigName'
    $IpConfig = '$IpConfig'
    $ip = '10.0.0.'
    $x = 25
    $PublicIP = $PublicIP + $i
    $IpConfigName = $IpConfigName + $i
    $IpConfig = $IpConfig + $i
    $x = 25 + $i
    $ip = $ip + $x
    #####################################
    # Create a public IP address
    $PublicIP = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
        -Name "$res1" `
        -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
        -Location $Location `
        -AllocationMethod dynamic
    #Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
    $IpConfigName = "$res2"
    $IpConfig = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
        -Name $IpConfigName `
        -Subnet $Subnet `
        -PrivateIpAddress $ip `
        -PublicIpAddress $PublicIP

}

$rand6 = -join ((1..10) | ForEach-Object { get-random -minimum 97 -maximum 122 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } })
$NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface `
    -Name $rand6 `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -NetworkSecurityGroupId $NSG.Id `
    -IpConfiguration $IpConfig0, $IpConfig1, $IpConfig2
```

**Error1 :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F8uq.png)

**Error2 :**
New-AzNetworkInterface: C:\Users\Marouane\Desktop\testpowershell\test2.ps1:95:22
Line |
95 |      -IpConfiguration $IpConfig, $IpConfig0, $IpConfig1
|                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot bind parameter 'IpConfiguration'. Cannot convert the "$IpConfig1" value of type "System.String" to type
| "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSNetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration".

**I want to increment the IP by 1
Ex : 10.0.0.25 next 10.0.0.26 next 10.0.0.27
but it says that you can't put in 'IpConfiguration' String ips
So what should i do ?
please help me!!
Thank you**

Comment: COuld you please tell me what you do in for loop? It seems that you create paramater ` $IpConfig` in three times.

Comment: Actually i will tell you what i want to do,

Comment: i want to increment some parameters by 1 like $ipconfig $Ipconfigname $publicip
and also 10.0.0.25 
i want the first $ipconfig1 $ipconfigname1 $publicio1 10.0.0.26
the second $ipconfig2 $ipconfigname2 $publicio2 10.0.0.27
3 : $ipconfig3 $ipconfigname3 $publicio3 10.0.0.28
all the other things stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Mainich you are trying do the array operation.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create to create an array of the below variable :

```
$PublicIP = $PublicIP + $i
$IpConfigName = $IpConfigName + $i
$IpConfig = $IpConfig + $i
```

For instance,

IpConfig1,Ipconfig2,Ipconfig3 -  and store the value accordingly.

Unfortunately, the implementation is slightly wrong

**Please note :** I have detailed the operation only for the $ipconfig variable. You can extend the same to other variables like `$IpConfigName,$PublicIP`

### What Exactly is Happening

For all the iteration, $IpConfig gets updated & the variables you intended IpConfig1,Ipconfig2,Ipconfig3  are not created through the above logic.

1. You are initializing the variable ipConfig as a string
2. Overwriting the value of the variable ipconfig with the string value
   $ipconfig1 (for the first iteration)
3. Overwriting the string value of the variable ipconfig with  object.

**AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig**

End of the iteration 1,
$ipconfig is with the value AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig
ipconfig1 is non existant.

### Suggestion :

The below creates an empty array with a fixed number - in your case 3 as $ipnumber = 3

```
$ipconfig = @() * $ipnumber

$ipconfig.append(New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
    -Name <>`
    -Subnet<>`
    -PrivateIpAddress <> `
    -PublicIpAddress <>)
```

( or )

```
$ipconfig[0] = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
        -Name <>`
        -Subnet<>`
        -PrivateIpAddress <> `
        -PublicIpAddress <>
```

Now you can access the values through ipconfig[0], ipconfig[1],ipconfig[2]
Or you can pass the $ipconfig directly -  as the parameter Ip configuration accepts the array value

`-IpConfiguration <PSNetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration[]>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-aznetworkinterface?view=azps-5.0.0

**Suggestion 2:**

if you would prefer creating the variable on the fly like ipconfig1,ipconfig2,ipconfig3, then you could do the below :

```
New-Variable -Name "Ipconfig$i" -Value <>
New-Variable -Name "Ipconfig$i" -Value <>
Get-Variable -Name "Ipconfig$i" -ValueOnly
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand you, i will try it and i will give you my feedback

Comment: Glad I could help.  if you have any query please feel free to let me know :) Also, Please consider marking it as answer if it had helped or

Comment: @MAINICHMarouane - did the above help  ?